# Remove ?= appended at the end of URL using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

How to remove ?= appended at any url even if no parameters are added to the request in Alamofire?

Sample Request :

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, headers: createHeader()).validate(statusCode: 200..<300).responseJSON {
        response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let data):
        print(“success”)
        break
        case .failure(let error):
        print(“failure”)
        break
        }
    }
```

> Where parameters: [String : String] = ["" : ""]
>
> createHeader() returns a dictionary for header like authorization, accept-language etc

Comment: Check if url string contains `?=`. If yes, then remove these characters.

Comment: Actually the url i am sending to Alamofire request does not contains ?= but Alamofire appends it. So i want to know from where can i remove this from being appended.

Comment: can you post a sample request you make in Alamofire so we can help you better?

Comment: @AceRivera Kindly check my edit

Comment: check my answer. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing parameters. Empty parameters in this case, **["" : ""]**.
Thus, the parameters is not nil

```
let parameters = ["" : ""] // this is not nil
```

["" : ""] is an instance of Dictionary ([String : String]) with empty data.
That's why the request still appends ?=

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check and update you. :)

Comment: alright. if you really have no parameters to pass, you can pass a "nil" in params, or just omit it in the code. the parameter is not required by the function and has a default value of nil

check Alamofire.swift (func request)

Comment: Thanks Ace!! It worked. Upvote if my question was right.